# Floating div right without allowing the div after to move up?

Tags: html, css

I may be using the wrong terminology, I apologize. But I'm trying to code a messaging UI and when I float the senders messages to the right, the messages to the sender get pushed up.

I've included a code pen below, where you can see exactly what I mean. If you remove `float: right;` from the `message-to` class then it will fix the issue, but it won't go to the right like its supposed to.

```css
html, body {
 background-color: red !important;
 height: 100%;
}

.messages-wrapper {
 padding: 20px 20px 0px 20px;
 background-color: #fff;
 width:448px;
 height: 100%;
}

.message {
 width: 300px;
 padding: 12px 15px 12px 15px;
 border-radius: 3px;
 margin-top:10px;
}

.message-to {
 background-color: #2C7CFF;
 color: #fff;
 float:right;
}

.message-from {
 background-color: #ebebeb;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-GB">
<head>
 <title>- NULL -</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.4.1/css/all.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/override.css" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
 <div class="messages-wrapper">
  <div class="message message-to">
   Hey man, how was your day after?
  </div>
  <div class="message message-to">
   Can you also bring your charger when you come round?
  </div>
  <div class="message message-from">
   It was alright, I'll tell you all about it later! No problem, I'm on my way now.
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please add a minimal working code snippet so we can actually help you

Comment: I did and got my answer, I decided to remove it.

Comment: And so you destroyed the question. You can either turn the question back to it's old state and maybe eloborate on what you want, delete the entire question or it is most likely to get deleted

Comment: It's my question, I'll do what I want with it. I don't want to return it to its old state. SO refused to delete it due to it having answers. Feel free to delete it SO.

Answer (score 1):

You can add `clear:both` to your message boxes

```css
html, body {
 background-color: red !important;
 height: 100%;
}

.messages-wrapper {
 padding: 20px 20px 0px 20px;
 background-color: #fff;
 width:448px;
 height: 100%;
}

.message {
 width: 300px;
 padding: 12px 15px 12px 15px;
 border-radius: 3px;
 margin-top:10px;
  clear:both;
}

.message-to {
 background-color: #2C7CFF;
 color: #fff;
 float: right;
}

.message-from {
 background-color: #ebebeb;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-GB">
<head>
 <title>- NULL -</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.4.1/css/all.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/override.css" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
 <div class="messages-wrapper">
  <div class="message message-to">
   Hey man, how was your day after?
  </div>
  <div class="message message-to">
   Can you also bring your charger when you come round?
  </div>
  <div class="message message-from">
   It was alright, I'll tell you all about it later! No problem, I'm on my way now.
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it all seems well up until the from messages don't follow the `margin-top: 10px;` rule on the `message` class. Is there a key reason for this? Also assigning it on its own class doesn't allow the div to be moved down.

Comment: This happens because the `.message-to` elements are floated and the `.message-from` elements are not. I have added a `float:left` for the `.message-from` elements in the above answer, this fixes your issue.

Answer (score 0):

```css
html, body {
 background-color: red !important;
 height: 100%;
}

.messages-wrapper {
 padding: 20px 20px 0px 20px;
 background-color: #fff;
 width:448px;
 height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.message {
 width: 300px;
 padding: 12px 15px 12px 15px;
 border-radius: 3px;
 margin-top:10px;
}

.message-to {
 background-color: #2C7CFF;
 color: #fff;
 float:right;
}

.message-from {
 background-color: #ebebeb;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-GB">
<head>
 <title>- NULL -</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.4.1/css/all.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/override.css" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
 <div class="messages-wrapper">
  <div class="message message-to">
   Hey man, how was your day after?
  </div>
  <div class="message message-to">
   Can you also bring your charger when you come round?
  </div>
  <div class="message message-from">
   It was alright, I'll tell you all about it later! No problem, I'm on my way now.
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```